# Store Radio Button selection as variable perl cgi script

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a perl script utilizing cgi where I have 2 radio buttons "uptime" and "localtime". When the submit button is selected I am looking to display the unix command uptime if the uptime radio button is selected and the perl function localtime if the "localtime" radio button is selected.

Below is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw/:standard/;

my $loctime = localtime;
my $utime = qx( /usr/bin/uptime );
my $q = new CGI;

print $q->header;

print $q->start_html(-title => 'A time select');

print $q->radio_group(
        -name => 'timeselect',
        -values => ['uptime', 'localtime'],
        -default => 'uptime',
        -columns => 2,
        -rows => 1,
        );

print $q->submit(
        -name => 'submit_form',
        -value => 'Submit',
);
```

I am assuming I need a subroutine or something along those lines that executes when the Submit button is clicked. Something like below

```
sub time_select {
      if (radio_button = uptime)
          {
          print $utime
          }
      else 
          {
          print $loctime
          }
```

I am not sure how to pass in what radio button is selected into my subroutine. Still new to perl and CGI so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on CGI and fetching params, it has a few different methods for fetching params you will be interested in from very simple to advanced, also a few things you need to be aware of if this is going to be used in any production type environment. https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI

When you create a new CGI object ( my $q = new CGI; ) it will build a list of parameters passed to it. To access the parameters you can call the param method on your CGI object.

Something simple like:

```
if ($q->param('timeselect')) {
    my $value = $q->param('timeselect');
    if ( $value eq 'localtime' ) {
        print localtime;
    } elsif ( $value eq 'uptime' ) {
        print `/usr/bin/uptime`;
    }
}
```

Will work fine for you, personally I would get rid of your uptime and localtime variables at the top to avoid them being called when there is no params passed.

Also another quick note on comparisons. When comparing strings you want to use eq and when comparing numbers you want to use ==.

Take care.